# How to use a single IAP product for multiple items with package:in_app_purchase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm currently developing an app with thousands of items that users can buy.

**What I'd like to do**

There are a large number of items and all of them have the same price, so I think it'd be better to use only one IAP product for those different items.

**What I won't do**

Another solution is to sell credits used to exchange for items.
I won't choose this solution unless it is the only option because I doubt it gives a good user experience.

**What I already know**

The items are actually not consumed (they remain in the app forever), but because a non-consumable product can be purchased only once, a consumable needs to be used instead.
The purchased items must be stored in a server to be shared across devices since Google and Apple don't provide the mechanism for restoring consumables.

**Question**

Below is a simplified version of the [code](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/22893085e4fa7ae83f8e84357dce81807b2665de/in_app_purchases/complete/app/lib/logic/dash_purchases.dart) from the [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases).

The data of the item that a user is about to purchase has to be passed from `[a]` to `[b]`, but it looks impossible. How can I do it instead?
Is it only that the Flutter package lacks the feature while the native side has a support for it? (Should I file an issue about it on GitHub?)

```
class DashPurchases {
  /// A method that is called when a user presses a purchase button.
  Future<void> buy(PurchasableProduct product) async {
    // [a]
    // Neither PurchaseParam nor buyConsumable() has a parameter/property
    // to hold additional data like the item that a user is about to buy.
    final purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: product.productDetails);
    await iapConnection.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
  }

  /// A callback function that is called when the purchase is finished, cancelled, etc.
  Future<void> _onPurchaseUpdate(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (var purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      await _handlePurchase(purchaseDetails);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handlePurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
      final validPurchase = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
  
      if (validPurchase) {
        // [b]
        // The item should be given to the user here, but I have
        // no idea how to identify the item that the user purchased.
      }
    }

    if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
      await iapConnection.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
    }
  }
}
```

I came up with the idea of adding the item to a queue (local DB or somewhere) at `[a]` and taking it out at `[b]`.
However, it has several problems as follows.

- It is quite cumbersome to track which item is pending or make the code robust. The purchase ID has to be added to the stored data to make it associated with the item as soon as `_handlePurchase()` is called so that the function can be retried after some failure in the backend.
- `purchaseDetails` has no purchase ID on `PurchaseStatus.error`. It is difficult to tell whether an item with no associated ID is the result of an error or it is still just pending.
- Multiple purchase details may be passed to `_onPurchaseUpdate()` in a different order than the actual purchases.

Resolving these will lead to very complicated code, and it doesn't seem very safe either.